# Label background is not visible in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The following css works perfectly in firefox but not IE(7). Why?
In IE 7 *height* and *width* is applied but no background is shown.

```
#field-wrapper label{
    background: url("images/1.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: I dunno, can we see your HTML or a test case?

Comment: 98% means the background will only show in the last 2% of the label on the right. Is that correct?

Comment: @Deadlykipper, I changed it to 0. still has problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is funny with image formats.

Does your jpg image use CMYK colors? Try saving it with RGB colors.

Can you use a .png or .gif image instead?  Beware the transparent .png files are buggy with IE6 and IE7!